# How can I reverse an image using html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to take an image in flip it upside down with html canvas. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhere in your javascript, where you draw your image, put context.scale(1, -1); And then after you draw your image, reset the scale by context.scale(1, 1);